# Can't add property "max-content" to @key-frames

Tags: javascript, css, angular, nativescript

i am trying to make a collapsible content, but the css won't accept the "max-content" property in animation. i get the error: "Invalid value: max-content" for the height of the content.
when i set the the height without @keyframes it works, but i want it to be animated

```
.full {
    animation-name: fullText;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .short{
    animation-name: shortText;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

@keyframes fullText {
    from { height: 150; }
    to { height: max-content; }
  }

  @keyframes shortText {
    from { height: max-content; }
    to { height: 150; }
  }
```

Comment: How do you get the error, and are you sure there is no error for `height:150;`?

Comment: @Mr Lister
In the console, and the program won't start.
i am sure, when i set hard coded values it works. I just want it to open automatically to the size of the text

Comment: have a look at https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: `max-content` is not supported by NativeScript.

Comment: @VISHAL SINGH i tried it, but max-height does not have any effect... event wihtout animation, it just ignoring it and show the full text

Comment: @odedbartov try max-height with unit 'px' or 'em' instead of '%' or max-content

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browser support max-content

https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content

Comment: this is nativescript. i am using android APK, not a browser

Comment: so you need to check 
is nativescript is support max-content?
maybe there's some alternate option to achieve this

Comment: as i said, without the animation/key-frame it works fine